# Remove Specific tag with Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to move my blog from WordPress to Pelican, but I'm stuck at removing these line using automatic script ?

```
[pro-player type="MP3"]http://domain/bla%20bla%20bla/a%20Lee%20yo%20-%20help.mp3[/pro-player]
[download id="79]
```

I've tried using :

```
sed -e 's/[pro-player type="[]*"]\([^[]*\).*/\1/p'
```

but no luck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *removing these lines*?  Your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: remove 
`[pro-player type="MP3"]http://domain/bla%20bla%20bla/a%20Lee%20yo%20-%20help.mp3[/pro-player]
[download id="79] `
part from my blog post.sorry for not clear with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove lines containing `[...]` from the file, say:

```
sed '/^\[.*\]$/d' inputfile
```

This would delete the lines starting with `[` and ending with `]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the file to get only URL's (which I assume from the regex you tried), you can use this:

```
cat file.txt | perl -n -e 'print $1 if /\](.*?)\[/'
```

Output:

```
http://domain/bla%20bla%20bla/a%20Lee%20yo%20-%20help.mp3
```

Comment: I want to remove these part from my post not just remove the tag itself. 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Within 'sed' the opening bracket introduces a character class, so if you want to match against it you need to escape it:

```
sed -e 's/\[pro-player type=[^\]*]\([^\]]*\)/\1/p'
```

I also changed your matching logic for "mp3".

Comment: that just remove the [pro-player type="MP3"] part from 
`[pro-player type="MP3"]http://domain/bla%20bla%20bla/a%20Lee%20yo%20-%20help.mp3[/pro-player]
[download id="79] `
but I want that script to remove these 2 line from my blog post on Pelican.